# Calculate the volume of a sphere using only double integrals

Tags: integration, geometry, analysis

I have to calculate the volume of a sphere using only double integrals.
We have the set

$$\mathscr D_1 := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x^2 + y^2 \le R^2 \}$$

- First question is to draw $\mathscr D$
- Second question is: Show that the volume of a cylinder of radius $R$ and height $2R$ is $2\pi R^3$ by means of the integral of a function $\mathscr D$.

My problem is we have to show that **by means of the integral of a function  $D$**...

Anybody can help me to start these two question please ?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question for information on how to attract quality answers. Proper formatting is expected; for information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [Tex](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/). It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: Thanks AlexR, no change added

Comment: Your sphere has turned to a cylinder ?

Comment: What are $\mathscr D$
, $\mathscr D_1$
 and $D$
 exactly ?

Comment: Yes, sphere has turned to a cylinder. $\mathscr D$, $\mathscr D_1$ and D are same things (D is my typographic error), I think $\mathscr D$ is just easier to write.

Comment: "The same things" still doesn't tell what they are. Domain ? Function ? Your description is somewhat draft.

Comment: Sorry, $\mathscr D$ is a set (maybe it's not the good word, english is not my mother tongue)

Answer (score 2):

The sphere is located with its center at the origin, and has radius $R$.

The surface of the sphere has equation: $$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R^2$$

We can rewrite this equation as $$z = \pm\sqrt{R^2 - x^2 - y^2}$$

Hence, by symmetry

$$Vol_{sphere} = 2\iint_G \sqrt{R^2 - x^2 - y^2}dxdy $$

where $$G = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 \leq R^2\}$$

a circle in the $x-y$ plane with radius $R$.

By a change on polar coordinates:

$$x = rcos(\theta),
y = rsin(\theta)$$

$$\sqrt{R^2 - (x^2 + y^2)} = \sqrt{R^2 - r^2}$$

$$dxdy = rd\theta dr$$

the integral becomes:

$$2 \int\limits_0^{2\pi} d\theta \int\limits_0^{R} r\sqrt{R^2 - r^2}dr$$

And after calculation, the desired result. Note that you do not need to do the change to polar coordinates, but the integral becomes much more difficult.

Analogue, you can prove the formula for the volume of a cylinder by considering the plane $$z = H$$ and integrating:

$$\iint_G H dxdy = H\iint_Gdxdy = H\pi R^2$$

where I used $$\iint_Gdxdy = A_G$$

Plugging in $$H = 2R$$ yields the result.

If you have any questions left, feel free to ask in a comment and I will edit my answer.

Comment: Are you sure that your answer has any connection to the OP ?

Comment: He/she edited his post I think. But he/she might be helped by the last part

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't edit my question, just some typographic correction.